# Can I run a shell script with different profile preferances of Terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, themes

For general use of terminal, I use a transparent theme. But for some purpose, I have a shell script which I would like to run with different profile/theme ( I mean with different foreground and background colors and opacity).

Can I do anything (Maybe like adding some code to my shell script) , so that I may start the shell script  with different profile.

PS: I'm on Ubuntu 15.04 and using bash, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not by modifying your script, no. The script has no knowledge of the terminal, the terminal is just a graphical window that runs a shell. However, assuming you're using `gnome-terminal`, you can choose the profile on the commandline:

```
gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=PROFILENAME
```

So, if you profile's name is `foo`, you could write a wrapper script (`script1.sh`) that executes your script (`script2.sh`) in a window with that profile:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=foo -x script2.sh
```

Now, if you run `script1`, it will open a new terminal with the right profile and run `script2` in it.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's exactly what I was looking for . It did the trick.